# Aggregate only Sequential values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with 3 columns

```
  Create table test 
(
        Created  Datetime
    ,   Flag     Bit 
    ,   Amount   Money
)
```

that looks like this

```
      Created              Flag    Amount
2019-12-01 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-11-21 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-11-06 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-10-04 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-09-08 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-08-04 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-07-24 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-07-23 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-06-01 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-05-05 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-04-25 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-02-03 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-02-02 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-01-31 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
2019-01-26 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-01-26 00:00:00.000    0        50,40
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000    1        50,40
```

As you can see it is ordered by `Created` in descending order.

Imagine that all these rows are Transactions. When the flag is one we have a checkpoint. So for example from line 20 to 17 is one period(Always counting from older to newer). From line 17 to 12 is another period and so on.

Please notice that in lines 9,8 and 7 we have 3 consecutive flags with a value of `1`. When this happens, having consecutive 1s without 0s, i want to treat all the consecutive 1s as a group. I want them to appear as one row with Summed amount and keeping the `MIN(Created)` of them.

For example for rows 9-7 I want to group it in one row with where `amount` has a value of `151.2`,`flag` a value of  `1` and `Created` a value of `2019-07-23 00:00:00.000` (the `min(date)` of the three rows.

An example output of this table would be the following.

```
Created                   Flag  Amount
2019-11-21 00:00:00.000   1     100,80
2019-11-06 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-09-08 00:00:00.000   1     100,80
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-07-23 00:00:00.000   1     151,20
2019-06-01 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-05-05 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-04-25 00:00:00.000   1     50,40
2019-03-11 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-02-03 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-02-02 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-01-31 00:00:00.000   1     50,40
2019-01-26 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-01-26 00:00:00.000   0     50,40
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000   1     50,40
```

Comment: Your sample output looks a lot like the input.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server and MySQL does not use T-SQL. I've removed the conflicting tags; please retag **only** the RDBMS you are really using. As for your post, what is your question here, you don't appear to have asked one. What have you tried to solve the problem, and why didn't it work?

Comment: The problem is that i want to reach the solution i have shown but i don't know the code to do it. I want help to do this!

Comment: *"I want help to do this!"* We still need to know what RDBMS you are really using first.

Comment: *"Please notice that in lines 9,8 and 7 we have 3 consecutive flags with a value of 1. When this happens, having consecutive 1s without 0s, i want to treat all the consecutive 1s as a group. I want them to appear as one row with Summed amount and keeping the MIN(Created) of them."*  That if the min date within this group has ties meaning the same date twice or multiple times? Then you have a problem as you don't have a order besides Created..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to collapse adjacent "1"s, then one approach is to assign a grouping based on the count of preceding 0s and aggregate.  So for aggregating the "1"s:

```
select min(created), 1 as flag, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - flag) over (order by created) as grouping
      from t
     ) t
where flag = 1
group by grouping;
```

This does not quite work when we include `0`s, because the `0`s would get combined with the `1`s.  So I think the simplest method is `union all`:

```
select min(created), 1 as flag, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             sum(1 - flag) over (order by created) as grouping
      from t
     ) t
where flag = 1
group by grouping
union all
select created, flag, amount
from t
where flag = 0;
```

I originally misinterpreted the question as wanting a summary for all periods, not just the adjacent "1"s.  You can do this with a cumulative sum to identify the groups:

```
select t.*,
       sum(flag) over (order by created) as grouping
from t;
```

And then use a subquery to aggregate this:

```
select min(created), max(created), count(*) as num_transactions,
       sum(amount) as total_amount
from (select t.*,
             sum(flag) over (order by created) as grouping
      from t
     ) t
group by grouping;
```

Comment: @PoNti3 comment was made on the wrong location, but i read it and added the SQL Server tag to the question..

Answer (score 0):

You want to aggregate all consecutive rows flagged 1. You can achieve this with a running count of rows flagged 0. You can see in the table below that flag + running count of zeros identifies the groups.

```
Created    | Amount | Flag | COUNT_0
-----------+--------+------+--------
2019-12-01 | 50,40  | 1    |       0   \   both rows flag=1, count_0=0 => one group
2019-11-21 | 50,40  | 1    |       0   /
2019-11-06 | 50,40  | 0    |       1   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=1 => one group
2019-10-04 | 50,40  | 1    |       1   \   both rows flag=1, count_0=1 => one group
2019-09-08 | 50,40  | 1    |       1   /
2019-09-01 | 50,40  | 0    |       2   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=2 => one group
2019-08-04 | 50,40  | 1    |       2   \
2019-07-24 | 50,40  | 1    |       2    |  all three rows flag=1, count_0=2 => one group
2019-07-23 | 50,40  | 1    |       2   /
2019-06-01 | 50,40  | 0    |       3   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=3 => one group
2019-05-05 | 50,40  | 0    |       4   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=4 => one group
2019-04-25 | 50,40  | 1    |       4   >   the only row with flag=1, count_0=4 => one group
2019-03-11 | 50,40  | 0    |       5   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=5 => one group
2019-02-03 | 50,40  | 0    |       6   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=6 => one group
2019-02-02 | 50,40  | 0    |       7   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=7 => one group
2019-02-01 | 50,40  | 0    |       8   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=8 => one group
2019-01-31 | 50,40  | 1    |       8   >   the only row with flag=1, count_0=8 => one group
2019-01-26 | 50,40  | 0    |       9   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=9 => one group
2019-01-26 | 50,40  | 0    |      10   >   the only row with flag=0, count_0=10 => one group
2019-01-01 | 50,40  | 1    |      10   >   the only row with flag=1, count_0=10 => one group
```

The related query:

```
select min(created), min(flag), sum(amount)
from
(
  select
    m.*,
    count(case when flag = 0 then 1 end) over (order by created) as count_0
  from mytable m
)
group by flag, count_0
order by min(created);
```